# Rails where clause in a many to many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i have two many to many models and another

Storetypes:

```
class Storetype < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :stores
end
```

Stores:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group  
  has_many :products
end
```

Groups:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stores
  has_many :storetypes
end
```

I need to do a query where i get all the stores on a storetype, im doing something like this:

```
@storetype_id = Storetype.first
@stores = @group.stores.where(@storetype_id => @group.stores)
```

any thoughts?

EDIT

The output i need is all the stores that belong to a certain storetype

Comment: Your description of the query doesn't explain very well what you want.  Give small tables and the desired query output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few problems here that I'll point out.

I assume you mean `Storetype.first` when you say `@storetype.first`. You're confusing the class and an *instance* of the class.
So say I do this:

```
@storetype = Storetype.first
```

I'm creating an instance of the class `Storetype`, which is your model. Get me?

So to answer your question, once I have an instance, I can now simply run

```
@storetype.stores
```

to all the stores on that storetype. See how I went the other way to your method? I also didn't need to use the id of the storetype at all. Much easier and cleaner.

For the other part of the relationship, to get all the storetypes of a store, you simply run (with an instance of `Store`)

```
@store.storetypes
```

Comment: man you are absoulutley right... I knew it was a simple thing, and my mind could't get a grasp on it... i need some rest... thanks any ways !

Comment: Great any time, you weren't far off at all. Ha same! No problem :)